# Populating 2D with a count from iteration

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
public void getSort(int []order, int[] chaos ){
        //int order has a list of numbers 0,5
        //chaos has a list of numbers 0,5  


    for (int s: order) {   


    int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0;i< chaos.length ;i++ )
        {

            if(chaos[i]==(s))
            {
                count++;
        }

    }
System.out.println("Score " +s+" Occur "+count);
    }
}
```

I needed help keeping the current number being checked, and the current count of that number being checked.
I wanted to place them into a 2D array to perform operations.

I attempted getting the output to a string by making a method that returned a string, however that returned the last number checked. 
I thought of capturing the system.out, however I need the data in an array anyway.

Comment: Please format well you code, It is difficult to understand your actual code

Comment: I edited things little bit but not sure about actual code looks like this.